# WPF Accelerator Keys like Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, hotkeys

I'm developing a large line of business app with C# and WPF.  Our standard is to include accelerator keys for buttons on all forms (Save, Cancel, Search, etc.).  I've recently noticed that when a form is loaded, the accelerator key is active even when the user does not press the "Alt" key.  For example, our Search button uses "Alt-H" as the accelerator, but the user can initiate a search by simply pressing "H".  I'm using the standard "_" in the button content to create the accelerator key.

```
<Button Content="Searc_h"/>
```

Has anyone else noticed this behavior and has anyone found a suitable workaround that requires the "Alt" key to be pressed?

Answer (score 11):

This is standard behaviour for accelerator keys on Windows whenever no text input is focused. Please don’t break it, just leave it in.

You can check this yourself. Press Win+R to bring up the "Run..." dialog, then Tab so one of the buttons is focused, then press "B". The "Browse" button will get activated.

This is also why you can answer those MessageBox prompts with a simple Y/N (instead of Alt+Y / Alt+N).

Comment: Absolutely. Definitely. Totally. The most frustrating thing for me (when I’m the *user*) is when *standard functionality* that works in *every single program* suddenly fails in some random program just because the programmer tried to do something clever, or even worse, *deliberately broke it*...

Comment: +1; dont ever make applications that work against the default behaviour of the OS.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put the underscore in at all, then add this to the window.

```
  <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="Help" Key="H" Modifiers="Alt"/>
  </Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: While this achieves what the OP asks for, for the love of god, Don’t. Break. Standard. Functionality. On. Purpose. All accelerator keys have always worked like that.

Comment: +1 because he was the ONLY one who answered the OP's question.  Maybe the OP does not have a choice in this?  Sometimes you have to do what you don't want to because your management requires it and it is your JOB if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Menu and ToolBar mnemonics work without pressing Alt key in WPF. This is the microsoft standard.
Refer the this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/14f6f49f-0027-471b-b68c-e7f6ba012012

Answer (score 1):

This article on [Sara Ford's Weblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2004/04/16/114935.aspx) discusses this phenomenon.

A commenter mentions this as a solution:

"If you're writing an application and you don't like this behavior, look up WM_CHANGEUISTATE and specifically the UISF_HIDEFOCUS flag."

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the Command pattern in WPF allows you more granular control over what keyboard shortcuts are allowed.  It goes a step further than the "_" in your button text.

Check the following link for more information:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands

Edit: previous link was dead - provided a new link.

-Doug

Comment: lol, it works for me this morning.  I wonder if their site has stability issues...

Comment: This is why you shouldn’t post answers that rely on a link. Just reiterate the actual answer in your post.