# Show underscore symbol when Alt pressed with KeyBinding specified

Tags: wpf

I have CommandBinding and KeyBindings inside window. Commands are activated with Alt modifier pressed. Is it possible to show underscore symbol with this binding?

ps I do not want to use underscore symbol into text, see here why [WPF hot key firing without modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688291/wpf-hot-key-firing-without-modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the content of your item prefaced with an underscore; when Alt is pressed, the underscore will become visible.

```
<Button Height="100" Width="200" Content="_MyButton"/>
```

If the concern is the firing of the `Command` when the Alt key modifier is not pressed; you can modify this behavior as noted by [Atanas](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/14f6f49f-0027-471b-b68c-e7f6ba012012/).

```
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressedEvent, new AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(OnAccessKeyPressed));
        }

        private static void OnAccessKeyPressed(object sender, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Handled && e.Scope == null && (e.Target == null))
            {
                //if alt key is not in use handle event to prevent behavior without alt key
                if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != ModifierKeys.Alt)
                {
                    e.Target = null;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This will prevent the `Command` from firing when the `Alt` modifier key is not pressed.

Comment: Read my post carefully - especially with "ps" part.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli I'm confused; where do you want the underscore to appear and when?

Comment: There is a usual behaviour for Win controls - when user press Alt, underscore appears - for example, when we have content="_MyButton". Unfortunately, Windows may (based on current user's machine settings) fire click on button event without Alt modifier. So I moved my control into KeyBinding, but now we should show "_" symbol manually when Alt is pressed.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli Added additional commentary; should get you where you need to be.